# no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, credentials

I am using shared_cred_file for aws provider. With aws provider version 3.63 for example, terraform plan works good.

When I use aws provider 4.0 it prompts me to use apply changed setting for shared_credentials_files. After the changes, there is no error, but the second error remains

what could be the problem?

```
Warning: Argument is deprecated
│
│   with provider[“registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws”],
│   on main.tf line 15, in provider “aws”:
│   15:   shared_credentials_file = “~/.aws/credentials”
│
│ Use shared_credentials_files instead.
│
│ (and one more similar warning elsewhere)
╵
╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│
│ Error: no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, canceled, context deadline exceeded
│
│
│   with provider[“registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws”],
│   on main.tf line 13, in provider “aws”:
│   13: provider “aws” {
│
```

```
///////////////////////////////
// Infrastructure init
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket                  = "monitoring-********-infrastructure"
    key                     = "tfstates/********-non-prod-rds-info.tfstate"
    profile                 = "test-prof"
    region                  = "eu-west-2"
    shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  }
}

    provider "aws" {
      profile                 = "test-prof"
      shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]
      region                  = "eu-west-2"
    }
```

```
    Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
        │
        │ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
        │ for more information about providing credentials.
        │
        │ Error: no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, canceled, context deadline exceeded
        │
        │
        │   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
        │   on main.tf line 13, in provider "aws":
        │   13: provider "aws" {
```

cat config

```
[test-prof]
output = json
region = eu-west-2
```

cat credentials

```
[test-prof]
aws_access_key_id = ****************
aws_secret_access_key = ******************
```

Comment: You don't have a `required_providers` block anywhere?

Comment: yes, I have it. i want to use v 4.0.0 of aws provider for my new module

Comment: I have a feeling it is related to the AWS SDK for Go v2: https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/.

Comment: probably, but I don't use Go in this module at all

Comment: You don't, but Terraform does. :)

Comment: ahha `:-D` yes)

Comment: Try explicitly setting the path to the credentials file instead of relying on home directory resolution.

Comment: Getting this error too as of provider v4.0.0. Perhaps linked to this feature?  
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/23080/files

Comment: @PaulRdt: yes, I think so. I am using v3.74.2 and have it working on an EC2 instance in a docker container that just has a role attached to it, and with v4.0.0 it's broken. See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23110 and https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23131

Comment: yes, we need to wait for a fix from hashicorp. only full path works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials_file = "$HOME/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "default"
  region                  = "us-east-1"
}
```

to

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials_file = "/Users/me/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "default"
  region                  = "us-east-1"
}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

By latest Terraform documentation this is how it will work,

```
provider "aws" {
  region                    = "us-east-1"
  shared_credentials_files  = ["%USERPROFILE%/.aws/credentials"]
  profile                   = "customprofile"
}
```

I had the same issue this thing works for me.

Comment: For me what worked was ```shared_credentials_file``` instead of ```shared_credentials_files``` and the value needed to be a string, not a list.

Comment: @LuisFelipe : it's `shared_credentials_files` based on [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#shared_credentials_files).

Comment: Using `shared_credentials_file` throws "unsupported argument" error for me in terraform v1.7.4. It has to be `shared_config_files` and `shared_credentials_files` lists per their docs.

Answer (score 4):

We stumbled with this issue in our pipelines after migration AWS Provider from version 3 -> 4.

So, for anyone using Azure DevOps or any other CI tools, the fix should be as easy as adding a new step in the pipeline and creating the shared credentials file:

```
mkdir $HOME/.aws

echo [default] >> $HOME/.aws/credentials
echo aws_access_key_id = ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} >> $HOME/.aws/credentials
echo aws_secret_access_key = ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} >> $HOME/.aws/credentials
```

*AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID* and *AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY* should be defined as a var or secrets in your pipeline.

[image: azure pipeline]

Comment: This worked for me as well. My terraform provider definition was specifying `profile = "something"` and setting just `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` env vars used to work fine, but after updating Terraform AWS Provider from 3 to 4 it broke. I tried setting `AWS_PROFILE` but that still didn't fix it. So I had to define the `[something]` profile in `~/.aws/credentials`, and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "your region"
  shared_credentials_file = "path_file_credentials like C:\Users\terraform\.aws\credentials"
  profile                 = "profile_name"
}
```

The path should be in this format: `%USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials`

This is the only acceptable format by the date of this answer, there are other ways too:

1.You can put your credentials in a `tf` file

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "profile_name"
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

2. If you are working on a project and don't want to share them with your teammates, you can use it as a variable like this:

- `main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "profile_name"
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
}
```

- `variables.tf`

```
variable "access_key" {
  description = "My AWS access key"
}
variable "secret_key" {
  description = "My AWS secret key"
}
```

You can either fill them after `terraform apply` or add `variables.tf` to `.gitignore`

You can find more options [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/secrets-management-with-terraform/).